# How to get product list where quantity is less than 10 in magento

Tags: database, product

I want product list in frontend where product quantity is less than 10

I wnat name,sku ,quantity

so how to get product with this condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a join with the cataloginventory/stock_item table to get the stock qty for a product, you could use:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
 ->getCollection()
 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
 ->joinField('qty',
             'cataloginventory/stock_item',
             'qty',
             'product_id=entity_id',
             '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
             'left')
 ->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array("lt" => 10));
```